# can not customize uibarbuttonitem, iphone

Tags: iphone, uitabbaritem

What I am having right now is (the uibarbuttonitem is connected to the one in header file)

[image]

Then I do customization like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    UIButton    *back   =   [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 32)];
    [back setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button01.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [back setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [back addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backButton =    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
}
```

However, after running my application, that uibarbuttonitem is not changed at all.I did try to put above codes in `initWithNibname` but no luck at all

Please advice me and point out if I have made a mistake in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;` at the end.

Comment: I dont use the navigationBar of the system. As you have seen, in the xib file above, I added my own navigation bar and add a uibar button it it.I should indicate this in the OP. Sorry about that..

Comment: so add it to your own navigation bar. You just assigned a new UIBarButtonItem object to the instance variable `backButton`. The UIBarButtonItem that is already present in your navigation bar is the same as before.

Comment: If you have a reference to the navigation bar, you can use the same code but instead of `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`, use `myCustomNavigationBar.leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch:thanks for pointing it out. I did create a new instance and not use the one in my navigation bar at all

Comment: @Ash Furrow: you are rite. I also can do that